# Is it necessary to install Dev-Express on machine to install a C# Application that uses Dev-Express controls..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Need Your Help..

I have developed one windows application in C#.Net (stand-alone application). It is basically a Image processing application.
While developing this application I have used Dev-Express controls for better performance. Now I have created the setup file of that application and tried to install it on few machines for testing purpose, while doing this I found that this application is getting install successfully on those machines which has Dev-Express installed on it, but getting failed to install on those machines which do not have Dev-Express setup.
So my question is- "How can I solve this problem..?". Because, as Dev-Express license copy is very costly, "I don't know whether my client will afford it or not". Please Help..!!

Comment: Do not include Dev-Express controls on your projects without knowing if clients need them, want them , or are going to pay for them...

Comment: Does your setup include all the DevExpress dll files required for the project? How are you creating your setup?

Comment: You own devexpress developer license or trail version?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Currently I'm using  "trail version".

Comment: If you have developer license you can deploy it to client machine(s). without any problem. If you deploy trial version it will work, but sometime it will explode saying *you're using trial version of devexpress* something like that. If you can bear that you can go ahead. But pls read trial license agreement from devexpress, If it is against to publish trial version then they may sue you. Don't give a chance for that. :)

Comment: @MelvinDVaz Yes "My setup include all the DevExpress dll files required for the project" Please see the link below, in that see the answer suggested by "Sakthi.Singaravel" I have used this method to create the setup file. Link is-- http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread8667-how-to-create-setup-file-in-visual-studio-2010-for-windows-application.aspx   Thank You..!

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: @Mikhail You are right.... I'm trying that...!!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to a separate license for the distribution (see the [Licensing FAQ](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/licensingfaq.xml) for more information).
However, you need to distribute the corresponding DevExpress runtime assemblies, because they obviously are not installed on clients' machines. This approach is common for distributing 3-rd party products. Consult the [DevExpress support](http://www.devexpress.com/sc) for further clarification.